# Casting an object to double

Tags: c#, .net

I inherited the following initialisation structure, where my parameter is a `double` number:

```
public void Init(IDictionary<string, object> dict)
{
  double val = (double)dict[MY_KEY];
}
```

This works fine if the object was really a `double`, e.g.

```
dict[MY_KEY] = 1.0;
```

but breaks when the object was a different numeric type, e.g. `int` as below:

```
dict[MY_KEY] = 1;
```

How can I change my method so that it works with all numeric types that can be implicitly converted to a `double`?

Comment: If at all possible I *strongly* advise you to avoid putting yourself in this position to begin with.  If you need a double, force people to put a double in, rather than accepting any possible type of number and trying to turn that into a double.  You'll be setting yourself up for a world of hurt otherwise.  Keep in mind that all of the numeric types have a different set of numbers they can represent.  Someone could put in a number that, to be converted to a double, requires a loss of information, which they won't expect.  The answers below seem like a magic bullet, but they're just not.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`Convert.ToDouble(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx3x7f55%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, instead of explicitly casting it.

```
public void Init(IDictionary<string, object> dict)
{
  double val = Convert.ToDouble(dict[MY_KEY]);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
double val = Convert.ToDouble(dict[MY_KEY]);
```

As long as dict[MY_KEY] is not null, if it is this will throw an Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be using the TryParse() method.  This would be a better option to use here since the method is public and you're attempting to convert an object to double which will throw an exception if the normal explicit or implicit conversion fails.

```
public void Init(IDictionary<string, object> dict)
{
    double val;

    if (!double.TryParse(dict[MY_KEY].ToString(), out val))
    {
        // Handle parse failure if necessary.
        // On failure, the return value of val will be 0
    }   
}
```

Here's the MSDN documentation if interested on some more specifics: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Of course, changing the type to double instead of object in the parameter as Servy mentioned would be the best option if possible so that no conversion would have to be performed.